# How to visualize errors of multilabel classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, data-visualization, multilabel-classification

For **multiclass** classification you would normally choose a confusion matrix to plot the error of predicted classes against the target classes.

What is the best way to visualize errors of **multilabel** classifiers? As multiple classes are predicted at once a mapping of prediction against target is not always possible so confusion matrices are generelly not suitable.

My first idea is to plot a bar chart where each class has a bar for missed and one for false predictions. But is there any standard for visualizing the errors which includes more information just like a confusion matrix for multiclass problems?